# Why is there a resistor inline with switch in blender motor?

Tags: resistors, motor, bridge

Our hand-held blender stopped working and I took it apart to see if I could fix  it (no, as it turned out).

The circuit was simple; a switch and a 0.47 Ohm (R47) resistor in series with a full bridge rectifier whose DC output was connected directly to the motor.

The wattage is 200 W and the voltage 120 V, so the voltage drop across the resistor is small.

Question: Why bother with the resistor?

**Note**: I am not looking to fix the device, I know one of the windings is burned out, but I am curious about the resistor! (I am an EE, and 'should' know these things,  but...)

**Added**: The labeling is R47 10%, and UTM 206-8. A quick look at the Jameco catalog gave me 'Power Wirewound Ceramic Resistors, axial'.

Comment: Check the Issm (surge current rating) rating of the bridge. The resistor may be necessary for surge protection on starting the motor.

Comment: Thanks! I need to pull the diodes to see if I can read the markings. One pair has GP (followed by 1 and possibly more symbols) with some symbol and the other pair has OJI with same symbol. I hooked up a digital multimeter directly to the brush terminals and this reads (the readings vary a lot) around 110-120 Ohm (at certain shaft angles).

Comment: Did it fail after rapid start-stops? I might expect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a fusible resistor designed to protect the wiring in case of a short in the bridge rectifier or the motor.

**It may also be a simple fuse**. If it is open, then it either has opened early or it has done its job. The 200W rating would seem to indicate a higher amperage of fuse, but perhaps that's a peak rating or something like that.

That item would be the first thing I'd check, and the second would be the bridge rectifier. Then the motor brushes.

Comment: Spehro, any chance it'd be a current shunt on a product like that?

Comment: @DanLaks I'd guess not. It would not serve any function I could think of.

Comment: Unless they had active current monitoring to detect an over-current. But I'd be surprised if a hand-held blender had such smarts in it.

Comment: It is in series with the switch, so not a shunt. The labeling is R47 10%, and UTM 206-8. A quick look at the Jameco catalog gave me 'Power Wirewound Ceramic Resistors, axial'.

Comment: Thanks for the fix suggestion! I know one of the windings doesn't work (the motor starts if I rotate a little, sometimes it starts on its own). The resistor is a puzzle for me, though.

Comment: Might be the brushes.

Comment: Might be, thanks - I tried tapping them a little but had no apparent effect. (Unfortunately taking it apart was an irreversible affair.)

Answer (score 2):

It could be a ntc - for softstart.

It could also have a capacitor parallel to it as an energy saving or a speed control  mechanism: the capacitor shorts out the resistor in start up but after the resistor is there to lower the current to control speed for example.

The 2nd approach is quite common for relays. Btw.

Answer (score 1):

R47 is 0.47 ohms so it acts like a fuse, depending on size, a 5w fuse. Common design decision -  than glass and metal, not designed to be user replaced.

Comment: Are you sure about that? What are the "fusing" characteristics of a common resistor? Like obviously it's going to start going over temp, but then what?